# How to show reference's page in internal links

Tags: cross-referencing, context, pandoc, pandoc-crossref

I'm using ConTeXt as a PDF engine with Pandoc, to convert from Markdown to PDF. I use [pandoc-crossref](https://lierdakil.github.io/pandoc-crossref/) to process internal cross references, for example "as seen in section 2.1". **Is there a way to add the reference page as a suffix**, like "as seen in section 2.1, page 45" (via ConTeXt, as pandoc-crossref knows nothing about actual document pages)?

The reference itself ("section 2.1" in my example) is turned into `\goto{section~2.1}[sec:sectionId]` in the intermediate ConTeXt file; this is done by pandoc-crossref via two options, `linkReferences: true` and `nameInLink: true`. The reference itself is generated as `\startsubsection[title={A title},reference={sec:sectionId}]` (`sectionId` is just an example).

The best solution would be via configuration, as then I would only change my Pandoc-ConTeXt template. If there's only a solution changing each link, I can then write a Pandoc-Lua filter to do that.

The reason to add the page is that I'm writing my doctoral dissertation, and my university's library strips out internal links in submitted PDFs, so showing the page is a way to keep the "linking" meaningful.

### Minimal working example

```tex
% Enable hyperlinks and PDF properties
\setupinteraction[state=start, focus=standard]
\definepapersize[default][A6, portrait]
\setuppapersize[default]

\starttext
\startchapter[title={A chapter},reference={sec:a-chapter}]

Link to \goto{section~1.1}[sec:a-section].\par
\input lorem \par

\startsection[title={A section},reference={sec:a-section}]

\stopsection
\stopchapter
\stoptext
```

[image: Generated document]

In above example, what I want is: in the cross-reference to section 1.1, ConTeXt inserts a suffix with the section page, turning it into "section 1.1, page 2".

Comment: [`\in`](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/in)/[`\at`](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/at)/[`\about`](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/about)?

Answer (score 0):

```
% Enable hyperlinks and PDF properties
\setupinteraction[state=start, focus=standard]
\definepapersize[default][A6, portrait]
\setuppapersize[default]

\starttext
\startchapter[title={A chapter},reference={sec:a-chapter}]

Link to \goto{section~1.1}[sec:a-section] \at{page}[sec:a-section].\par
\input lorem \par

\startsection[title={A section},reference={sec:a-section}]

\stopsection
\stopchapter
\stoptext
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).